# Mongodb find returns nothing and possibly crashes

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which has around 6200 documents and its ever growing. When I use find() to query mongo, it returns nothing, and possibly crashes, but when I apply findOne or even find(params) params indicating conditions/queries then I do get results. The find() query use to work until around I had 5500 documents, after which it stopped working. Is there a limit to the number of documents find() can fetch? Is there anyway I can get all the documents?

Comment: I was unable to find any documents on findMany(). Could you share the link for the same. Thanks!